# Unable to Login if File is null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm using Firebase in flutter Project it's simple Login/ Signup. I have check isLogin mode or not everything is working fine in signup mode but not able to login.

It's giving error like this => **Null check operator used on a null value**

My variables:

```
bool isLoginMode = true;
  String? _userEmailId;
  String? _userName;
  String? _userPassword;
  File? _userImage;

 

    void _submitForm() {
      final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
       if (_userImage == null && !isLoginMode) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
         const SnackBar(content: Text('Please select Image'),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }
    if (isValid) {
      _form.currentState!.save();
      widget.submitFn(
        _userEmailId!,
        _userName ?? '',
        _userPassword!,
        _userImage!,
        isLoginMode,
        context, );
    }}
```

Comment: One or more of you variables with null check (!) are actually null. From the code you posted, it is not possible to tell which.

Comment: @PeterKoltai thanks I fixed you right image file was null thanks.